# Auto-refresh field generated by trigger

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, playframework-1.x

I use play framework 1.2.5.3 (with Hibernate 3.6.10), postgreSql 9.2.9.

I have table **requests** with column **uid** that I want to generate by custom rules described in my postgreSql trigger (before insert trigger set uid value).

I want to use generated value in my code. I have following models:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "requests")
...
public class Request extends GenericModel {

    ...

    @Column(name = "uid", length = Domains.SHORT_STRING)
    public String uid;

    ...
}
```

The complexity associated with inheritance models

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "kindergartenrequests")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
public class KindergartenRequest extends Request {

    ...

    private static KindergartenRequest create(...) {

         KindergartenRequest request = new KindergartenRequest(...); // put null uid
         request._save();

         Logger.debug(request.uid); // uid is still null here

         ...
    }
}
```

I tried following:

- Defining getter on uid field:

```
    
    public String getUid() {

        if (this.uid == null) {
            this.refresh();
        }

        return this.uid;
    }
```

- Defining post persist callback:

```
    
    @PostPersist
    private void afterSave() {

        if (this.uid == null) {

            this.uid = Request.em()
                .createNativeQuery("SELECT uid FROM requests WHERE id = :id")
                .setParameter("id", this.id)
                .getSingleResult()
                .toString();
        }
    }
```

But there is no effect in the KindergartenRequest class.

And I don't want to refresh it manually on each request creation. Like that:

```
request._save();
request.refresh();
```

Comment: Have you looked into why the `@PostPersist` method is not working. Is it not being called?

Comment: @PostPersist method was called and put into uid correct value, but in the KindergartenRequest class was still null. I tried it again now and it works perfect. Maybe I need to restart play.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well actually **@PostPersist** method works fine. Probably play must be full-restarted after some changes.

Comment: I've found that **@PostPersist** method fails when I called `new Request()` instead of `new KindergartenRequest()` and than `request.save()`. **javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query**